# Method to get all trainings

Tags: dialogflow-es

We need to get all trainings to process them for statistical purpose. 
We're using API to query our chatbot.

Is it possible to get trainings via an other API query or by an other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a API for training.  Any approved trainings are created as `user-says` examples for the relelvent intents.  You can retrive these `user-says` examples through the `GET /intents/[ID]` API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents#get_intentsid

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A good improvement would be to allow dialogflow'users to filter trainings by date or Request numbers.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct and/or upvote if you found it helpful.